# How to validate authorization header in nestjs?

Tags: validation, nestjs

How can i validate *Authorization* header, and check if it is uuid version 4 or not in nestjs?
I cannot use `@Headers(new ParseUUIDPipe()) token: string`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Headers are not available to be used with pipes. The reason being is that there could be an unknown number of headers and that possibly lead to a problem with validation. If you need to validate a single header, I'd suggest using either a guard or a n interceptor, depending on if you want to return a `BadRequestException` or an `UnauthorizedException`

Comment: Can i use something like this `next.handle().pipe(ParseUUIDPipe)` in the interceptor?

Comment: Nope. That's not how pipes work. If you wanted to instantiate the pipe on your own, you could do that, and then call the validate method, but a simple UUID v4 check isn't too difficult either.

Comment: I need to validate it before authorization strategy kicks in. Seems like interceptor comes after it, or am i wrong?

Comment: Both Pipes and Interceptors run after guards do. The only thing that runs before a guard is a middleware, [as described here](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/request-lifecycle)